# How to get random values in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json string in javascript variable . I want to get random value from JSON string and set into HTML.

```
var jsonContent= {
          "featured": [
            {
              "id": "111",
              "title": "post title 111",
              "desc": "This is a test desc 111"
            },
            {
              "id": "222",
              "title": "post title 222",
              "desc": "This is a test desc 222"
            },
            {
              "id": "333",
              "title": "post title 333",
              "desc": "This is a test desc 333"
            }
    ]
};
```

for e.g first key value assign to my html like this:-

```
   <div class="r-v-details">
    <span class="r-v-title">post title 111</span>
    <span class="r-v-description">This is a test desc 222</span>
   </div>
```

How can I get random key values from JSON string? Does I need to parse JSON into array then I can get random value? or I can achieve this by json only?
Can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be: (check result in console)

```
var jsonContent = {
        "featured": [
            {
                "id": "111",
                "title": "post title 111",
                "desc": "This is a test desc 111"
            },
            {
                "id": "222",
                "title": "post title 222",
                "desc": "This is a test desc 222"
            },
            {
                "id": "333",
                "title": "post title 333",
                "desc": "This is a test desc 333"
            }
        ]
    }

    var random = jsonContent.featured[Math.floor(Math.random() * jsonContent.featured.length)];
    console.log(random)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var random = jsonContent["featured"][Math.floor(Math.random()*jsonContent["featured"].length)];
```

Comment: @Jochem : Your solutions work for me. Thanks :) You can paste as a answer